# Spring MVC - Base View

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, view

In my project I actually use normal JSP and JSP-Tags for develop the views. But I'm looking for an easier way to develop views.
My general idea was that I have a base view which contains the skeleton of every page and all my specfic views should be rendered into these base view.

My solution is that I create an interceptor which will be executed after the "child view" is rendered and put this output into the base view which will rendered manually.

What do you say? - The JPS-Tag way or the interceptor way?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be looking for some kind of templating solution. You could use custom JSP tags which perhaps you are currently using to create and reuse parts of JSP pages such as headers and footers.

You could consider using a template engines like [Apache Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/) or decorators like [Sitemesh 2](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh/Home).

Take a look at the custom UI themes support in Spring MVC this may be what you are looking for.